# Limit exceeded error when deploying

Tags: community, custom-object, deployment

When deploying our account custom fields to the org through ant we have the following error:
1. objects/Account.object (Account.ValidatedBillingPostalCode__c) -- Error: limit exceeded (line 121, column 13)
2. objects/Account.object (Account.ValidatedBillingState__c) -- Error: limit exceeded (line 101, column 13)
3. objects/Account.object (Account.ValidatedBillingStreet__c) -- Error: limit exceeded (line 112, column 13)
4. objects/Account.object (Account.ValidatedShippingCity__c) -- Error: limit exceeded (line 3,

Subsequently various other components fail because they are dependent on the account fields. No existing custom fields are visible in the accounts > fields section of the org setup.

Please assist

Comment: Did you check your org data storage limit ?

Comment: Org Data storage limit is there

Comment: Did you check whether the data passed exceeds the data types length? Can you post the data type and length of the populated data

Comment: It is not data storage issue because it is happening while deploying. what type of field is this? It seems like that you are hitting field limit in PROD

Comment: It seems that the deleted data is causing this. May be needs to the PD

Comment: As @Himanshu said, you may be hitting the #of custom fileds allowed on Account. You'll need to delete/erase unneeded fields first, then deploy the new fields